# Problem regarding meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Is  the following statement  is true/false

the meromorphics  function  $f(z) =\frac{e^{iz}}{\cos z}$  never  assumes  $0$ and  $2$

My attempt : i thinks  this statement is True  because meromorphic mean  that it is analytic everywhere except of countably many points, where $f$ has poles. It is analytic in a neighborhood of $0,$

Is its true  ?

Comment: Yes, it's meromorphic, but does it take the values $0$ and $2?$

Comment: @saulspatz i thinks it will take  the value  2  but  not  0

Comment: No, it doesn't take the value $2$ either.  Write in the definition of $\cos{z}$

Comment: @Saulspatz  u mean    $cosz = \frac{e^{iz} -e^{-iz}}{2}$

Comment: Exactly.  Substitute that in and see what happens.